# How to Enforce Maximum Authentication Time in OpenSSH Configuration?

Tags: openssh

I'm attempting to enhance the security of my OpenSSH server configuration by enforcing a maximum authentication time limit. However, upon trying to implement this by adding the `MaxAuthAge` option to the `sshd_config` file, I encountered an error indicating that the option is not recognized. Despite searching through the OpenSSH documentation, I couldn't find a direct method to set a maximum authentication time.

What is the recommended approach for enforcing a maximum authentication time limit in OpenSSH? Are there alternative methods or configurations that can effectively achieve this goal? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the error message I encountered when attempting to validate the configuration:

```bash
$ /usr/sbin/sshd -tT

  /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 100: Bad configuration option: MaxAuthAge
  /etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

- **`sshd_config`:**

  ```ini
  # NAME: LALATENDU HARDENED OPENSSH CONFIGURATION
  # AUTHOR: LALATENDU
  # DATE CREATED: MARCH 02, 2024
  # LAST UPDATED: MARCH 02, 2024

  AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
  AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
  AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
  AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

  Protocol 2

  PermitRootLogin no

  PermitTunnel no

  Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

  PasswordAuthentication no

  ClientAliveInterval 180
  ClientAliveCountMax 2

  GatewayPorts no

  DisableForwarding yes

  AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
  AllowUsers lalatendu

  AllowStreamLocalForwarding no

  Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
  MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
  KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
  HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-ed25519

  MaxSessionsPerUser 2
  MaxAuthTries 3
  MaxSessions 2
  MaxAuthAge 600
  LoginGraceTime 30
  MaxStartups 3:50:10

  PermitEmptyPasswords no
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
  HostbasedAuthentication no
  UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox

  StrictModes yes

  X11Forwarding no

  AllowTcpForwarding no

  StrictModes yes

  IgnoreRhosts yes

  PrintMotd yes
  PrintLastLog yes
  Banner /etc/issue.net

  Compression no

  LogLevel VERBOSE

  AllowAgentForwarding no

  TCPKeepAlive no

  UseDNS no

  Match Address 192.168.1.100
      AllowUsers lalatendu
      PermitOpen any
      PermitRootLogin no
      X11Forwarding yes
      PasswordAuthentication no

  DenyUsers ubuntu centos admin
  DenyGroups docker
  ```

Comment: `chacha20-poly1305` is [exploitable](https://jfrog.com/blog/ssh-protocol-flaw-terrapin-attack-cve-2023-48795-all-you-need-to-know/) and should not be used _(same with any AES CBC cipher using etm MACs)_